# Mostrar Mensaje cuando no existan datos en un Await http

Tags: flutter, alertdialog

Hola estoy consumiendo un api-rest y me trae los datos sin problema, pero cuando no trae datos se me va por una exception en el cual dice "RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0", explico un poco el codigo que tengo

```
Future<T?> _callGetApi<T>({
required String endpoint,
required Map<String, String> params,
required T Function(Map<String, dynamic> data) builder,}) async {
try {
  
    var uri = Uri.http(_baseUrl, endpoint);
    var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri)
      ..fields.addAll(params);
    var response = await request.send();
    final respStr = await response.stream.bytesToString();
    print(
      jsonDecode(respStr),
    );
    final decoded = json.decode(respStr);
    print(decoded['message'][0]);
    return builder(decoded['message'][0]);




}
catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

}

```
Future<Userchatbot?> getDataPS(String cedula) async{
return _callGetApi(
  endpoint: _office,
  params: {'userapi':'usuario',
    'token':'\$2a\$07\$asxx54ahjppf45sd87a5auZi',
    'comando':'lista-clientes',
    'documento': cedula},

  builder: (data) => Userchatbot.fromJson(data),
);
```

Este seria el codigo en el cual consumo el api y me trae los datos, he puesto un try y catch para controlar la excepcion, a continuacion tengo mi pantalla de consulta en la cual ingreso el numero de cedula, y si no existe deberia mandar un showalert, lo hago en un future builder.

```
FutureBuilder<Userchatbot?>(
                                future: getDataPS(cedula),
                                builder: (BuildContext context,
                                    AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                    return Text("Trajo datos de Playas y STA");
                                  }
                                  
                                  else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                    return Icon(Icons.error_outline);
                                  } else {
                                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                                  }
                                });
```

al entrar en un error por "RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0" no dibuja el widget, como se soluciona esto, gracias ante mano

```
Future<Userchatbot?> getDataPS(cedula) async
{
  try {
    final dataSource = RestDataChatbot();
    final name = await dataSource.getDataPS(cedula);
    print(name);
    return name;
  }
  catch (e)
  {
    print(e);
  }
```

Comment: Puedes agregar en tu pregunta la función getCedula?

Comment: listo @JonathanPerez a esa te refieres? porque de ahi a lo que hago es enviarle ese campo a la funcion, pero repito si me consulta, el problema está en cuando no retorna nada se me va a una exception y no me muestra nada

Comment: claro, te sugiero que manejes el statusCode la respuesta, para que así puedas validar referente al código y hacer que continue con la ejecución o parar si no te retorna nada

Comment: @JonathanPerez he seguido tu sugerencia y haciendo un seguimiento ingresa por statuscode 200 pero de ahi ya al retornar se cae

Comment: Que te imprime el body de la respuesta? tanto cuando la respuesta si te trae algo, como cuanto te bota el error, que te imprime en ambos escenarios?

Comment: cuando hago el print a la variable respStr me devuelve "{"message":[]}" que seria el json vacio

Comment: Ya entiendo el error, pero lo que no entiendo es donde llamas a la funcion _callGetApi<T>, muestras un FutureBuilder donde llamas a getDataPS

Comment: @JonathanPerez he agregado la parte donde llamo a callGetApi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, lo que logre entender en los comentarios es que la respuesta de "message" puede traerte datos o puede venir vacía, entonces el problema que veo, es que cuando te retorna el "message" vacío tú aún así estas intentado convertila en un objeto `UserChatBot`, lo que tienes que hacer es validar que este message no te venga vacío y así no continue con el proceso, para evitar el error, primero vamos a hacer una pequeña validación en la función `getDataPS`:

```
 Future<T?> _callGetApi<T>({
required String endpoint,
required Map<String, String> params,
required T Function(Map<String, dynamic> data) builder,}) async {
try {
  
    var uri = Uri.http(_baseUrl, endpoint);
    var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri)
      ..fields.addAll(params);
    var response = await request.send();
    final respStr = await response.stream.bytesToString();
    print(
      jsonDecode(respStr),
    );
    final decoded = json.decode(respStr);
    if(decoded['message'].isNotEmpty){
        print(decoded['message'][0]);
        return builder(decoded['message'][0]);
    }else{
     print("data:" + decoded['message']);
    }
}
catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

Y aca validaríamos que la data no sea nula:

```
    Future<Userchatbot?> getDataPS(String cedula) async{
return _callGetApi(
  endpoint: _office,
  params: {'userapi':'usuario',
    'token':'\$2a\$07\$asxx54ahjppf45sd87a5auZi',
    'comando':'lista-clientes',
    'documento': cedula},

  builder: (data) {
     if(data != null){
       Userchatbot.fromJson(data)
     }
   },
);
```

De ahí tu podrías implementar más codigo para lograr el resultado que deseas.